# How to push a comment from a comment section into an array using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, node.js, express

This is my js code that's part of a website:

```
var user = {
  username: " ",
  comment: " "
};
var array = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mybutton").click(function() {
    user.comment = $("#comment").text();
    user.username = $("#username").text();
    array.push(user);
    alert(array[0]);
    user.empty();
  });
});
```

I have the alert to test my code. Both the #comment and #username are id tags to two textareas in my index.hbs file. Every time I push the button I get an alert with [object Object]. I don't know what's wrong with my code but I think it's because user.username and user.comment doesn't send the actual comment and username to the object user.

Comment: `array[0]` is an object and hence you are getting [object] as alert. If you want to check the output use console.log() instead. Or `JSON.stringify(array[0])`

Answer (score 1):

use `.val()` instead of `.text()`

e.g.

```
user.comment = $("#comment").val();
```

also, for your alert you have to ;

```
alert(array[0].username);
```